# get the correct url for an folder in wp-includes wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added a folder called `json` in my `wp-includes` folder. This folder called json has a file inside called `users.json`. I am trying to write to this file but am getting the following error:

> failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable
>   connections

I have been referencing it like the following in my php:

`$file = "http://www.fakeurl.com/wp-content/json/users.json";`

I believe I need to reference as per the name on the server. Is there a built in way to get this in wordpress?

Something like `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>`

Answer (score 5):

```
$url = includes_url();
echo $url;
```

this will Output: http://www.example.com/wp-includes/

Please also check file permission which you have created.

Answer (score 0):

You should use includes_url(); to point to a file in the wp_includes folder.

Example: includes_url().'/js/jquery.min.js';